# Bch to btc wrong operation

Tags: bitcoin-cash, cross-chain-recovery

Hello there I mistakenly sent your bch look to btc I would like your support TX : a235d00a0b215aac84df3f316ee75993d6c7021547e46c932456fa13abf43600

Btc.  1DG834n6U1VyuTPbWBKpRFpTQ48uHfrK1w